# Angular is not able to find required controller in directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am trying to create series of directives which cummunicates via controller. This is what I have now:

```
angular.module('drmApp')
  .directive('formInput', function () {
    return {
      templateUrl: 'views/directives/forminput.html',
      restrict: 'E',
      controller: 'ForminputCtrl',
      controllerAs: 'ctrl',
      bindToController: true,
      transclude: true,
      scope: {
        model: '=',
        errors: '=',
        property: '@',
        label: '@',
        form: '=?',
      },
      link: function postLink(scope, element, attrs, ctrl, $transcludeFn) {
        console.log($transcludeFn());
      }
    };
  })
  .directive('formInputValidationSummary', function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      require: '^formInput',
      transclude: true,
      link: function postLink(scope, element, attrs, ctrl, $transcludeFn) {
        ctrl.setValidationSummary($transcludeFn);
      }
    }
  })
  .directive('formInputContent', function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      require: '^formInput',
      transclude: true,
      link: function postLink(scope, element, attrs, ctrl, $transcludeFn) {
        ctrl.setInput($transcludeFn);
      }
    }
  });
```

HTML Markup:

```
<form-input model="entity"
    label="{{ 'WYKONAWCA_COLOR' | translate }}"
    errors="errors"
    property="color"
    form="form">
    <form-input-content>
        <input colorpicker="rgb" ng-model="model.color" type="text">
    </form-input-content>
</form-input>
```

Sadly, currently I am receiving this error:

```
Error: [$compile:ctreq] Controller 'formInput', required by directive 'formInputContent', can't be found!
```

I am using latest angular from v1.4 series. Also, this does not work with angular ~1.3. Is there something that I have forgot about? Did I misunderstand directive features?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are transcluding `transclude: true`, Angular yanks the transcluded content out of the DOM - so, `<form-input-content>` is now not a child of `<form-input>`.

Then, when you are invoking the transclude function, this links the directive - and at that time it complains about not being able to find the parent `formInput` controller.

When you transclude, be sure to place the transcluded content back in the DOM:

```
link: function postLink(scope, element, attrs, ctrl, $transcludeFn) {
   $transcludeFn(function(transcludedContentClone){
      // this happens prior to linking of transcluded content
      element.append(transcludedContentClone);
   });

   // ...
}
```